# PHP: Merge multiple JSON encoded lines

Tags: php, arrays, json

When users keep interacting with my web app, the pages keep doing calls so that some info can be stored in a cookie linked file that is stored on the server (with the PHP session file, it gets complex: I don't have choice to see a complete history, etc.)

So, anyway, with every ajax call, I create json_encoded data in a flat file with the unique cookie name.

Data example of one such cookie file: (keys/values may repeat)

```
{"name":"John Doe"}
{"email":"john@doe.com"}
{"location":"Disneyland, Orlando"}
{"country of residence":"Iceland"}
{"name":"Gill Bates"}
{"email":"Gill.Bates@sicromoft.com"}
```

Now, when I am searching this file, to retrieve data and to do other stuff, I would like to have the entire contents in one big array as if the entire data ws json_encoded in one shot.

How do I do this? I could do a bunch of str_replace and replace the "{" and "}" and get rid of the carriage returns but that seems to be a bit ugly

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to fix your json format by using str_replace as you saying because this is the only way to have a valid json format on using this function:

```
$str = '{"name":"John Doe"}
{"email":"john@doe.com"}
{"location":"Disneyland, Orlando"}
{"country of residence":"Iceland"}
{"name":"Gill Bates"}
{"email":"Gill.Bates@sicromoft.com"}';
$fix_json = "[" . str_replace("}\n{", "},{", $str) . "]";
```

and after this you can decode you json and convert it with json_decode, like this:

```
$dataArray = json_decode($fix_json, true);
```